# Apache VirtualHost partially ignored

Tags: windows, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I'm running a local server on windows and I want to provide lan access to a specific part of it whenever a variable is defined. It works fine, except the main config is served instead of the virtual host.

I've specifically made the virtual host point to a forbidden directory with the wrong `DirectoryIndex` to make sure it actually works, but the page is always served correctly, no matter what I do. Here's the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost ${LANIP}:${PORT}>
    DocumentRoot ${SRVROOT}/htdocs/phpinfo
    ServerName ${LANIP}:${PORT}
    DirectoryIndex index.pl
</VirtualHost>
```

and here's the [complete httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/DHEsqbW9), stripped of comments.

When I use `httpd -DLANACCESS -S`, this is the output:

```
c:\fauna\apache\bin>httpd -DLANACCESS -S                                
VirtualHost configuration:                                               
192.168.1.6:80         192.168.1.6 (C:/fauna/apache/conf/httpd.conf:464)
ServerRoot: "c:/fauna/apache"                                           
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/fauna/apache/htdocs"                             
Main ErrorLog: "c:/fauna/apache/logs/error.log"                         
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults                                        
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults                                        
Mutex default: dir="C:/fauna/apache/logs/" mechanism=default            
PidFile: "c:/fauna/apache/logs/httpd.pid"                               
Define: LANACCESS                                                        
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS                                                      
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG                                                     
Define: FAUNAROOT=/fauna                                               
Define: WIN_FAUNAROOT=C:\fauna                                         
Define: SRVROOT=/fauna/apache                                           
Define: WIN_SRVROOT=C:\fauna\apache                                     
Define: PERLPATH=C:\fauna\perl                                          
Define: WIN_PERLPATH=C:\fauna\perl                                      
Define: LANIP=192.168.1.6                                                
Define: PORT=80
```

This, I think, indicates Apache is correctly identifying that there is a `VirtualHost` directive, but is ignoring everything within it or somehow it doesn't match. No matter what, if I path to `localhost` from the server or `192.168.1.6` from another machine on the lan, it serves the same page. It respects permissions, but from the lan it should break and give a 404 with this test config, not serve the main site.

I even tried overriding the default vhost:

```
<VirtualHost _default_>
    DocumentRoot ${SRVROOT}/htdocs/nothing
    ServerName localhost:80
</VirtualHost>
```

which gives this output from Apache:

```
c:\fauna\apache\bin>httpd -DLANACCESS -S
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [c:/fauna/apache/htdocs/nothing] does not exist
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.1.6:80         192.168.1.6 (C:/fauna/apache/conf/httpd.conf:464)
*:80                   localhost (C:/fauna/apache/conf/httpd.conf:474)
ServerRoot: "c:/fauna/apache"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/fauna/apache/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "c:/fauna/apache/logs/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/fauna/apache/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "c:/fauna/apache/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: LANACCESS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: FAUNAROOT=/fauna
Define: WIN_FAUNAROOT=C:\fauna
Define: SRVROOT=/fauna/apache
Define: WIN_SRVROOT=C:\fauna\apache
Define: PERLPATH=C:\fauna\perl
Define: WIN_PERLPATH=C:\fauna\perl
Define: LANIP=192.168.1.6
Define: PORT=80
```

So, apparently, it *does* parse the `VirtualHost` tags. However, this has the exact same effect and both virtualhosts are completely ignored, as if they don't match.

edit - I have confirmed through `mod_info` that the `VirtualHost` *does* indeed match, but of course `DocumentRoot` and `DirectoryIndex` are completely ignored for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Unless I'm mistaken, setting up aliases on the main server requires setting them up separately in virtualhosts, otherwise the main site gets served due to aliases, especially if you've aliased `/` like I had. Not 100% sure of this but it makes sense based on what I got.**

I seem to have solved it using this definition for the virtualhost:

```
<IfDefine LANACCESS>
    <VirtualHost ${LANIP}:${PORT}>
        Alias "/" "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/phpinfo/"
        # DocumentRoot ${SRVROOT}/htdocs/phpinfo
        <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/phpinfo">
            AllowOverride None
            # Options -ExecCGI
            Require ip 192.168.1
            # DirectoryIndex phpinfo.php
        </Directory>
        Redirect 404 /info
        Redirect 404 /status
        ServerName ${LANIP}:${PORT}
    </VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
```

Previously, access would register as going through the virtual host, but would serve the main page. By aliasing `/` with the intended `DocumentRoot`, it serves the intended page properly. `Directory` is necessary to set proper permissions, otherwise it seems to inherit from the previous `Directory` definition or go with defaults or something. Thus, if your previous `Directory` definition requires amending, do so.

`DocumentRoot` apparently has no effect. I don't know why, but removing it from the main config seems to have no effect there either. Perhaps the way I set things up overrides it.

If you're using `Location` for things like `mod_info` or otherwise, use `Redirect 404` to cancel those locations or `Require` to forbid access, otherwise they operate as normal, regardless of any `Alias` directives you've set up.

Unless you set up `Alias`es for the rest of the server locations, previous ones appear to be inactive when overriding `/` or for some other reason I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely falling victim to windows filesystem virtualization, where files edited by non-Administrator appear changed for you but not for httpd running as a service.

Edit your configuration with the true Administrator account.

Comment: I am not running apache as a service since this setup is still in the development phase. I manually start and stop apache from the command line. The `-S` switch pretty much indicates this is not a problem of apache not seeing the changed config file and every time I change something I know will have an effect, it behaves as expected. Also, my user is an administrator. I know what you mean by "true" administrator, but as I've indicated, this doesn't seem to be the issue at all.